# Enable avatars in Gerrit 2.14

Tags: gerrit

I have installed external avatar plugin for Gerrit.

*gerrit.config*:

```
[avatar]
   url = https://outlook.office.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetPersonaPhoto?email=%s
```

Is there a way to replace `%s` for email? Because `%s` is taking username by default.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [avatars/external](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/admin/repos/plugins/avatars/external) plugin? This plugin was deprecated and replaced by the [avatars-external](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/admin/repos/plugins/avatars-external) plugin. In the new plugin you can use something like this:

```
url = http://example.org/avatars/${user}.jpg
```

See more info [here](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/avatars-external/+/refs/heads/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md)

You could try to use ${user} or maybe it's time to update your plugin.